# bash: export: `“JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home”': not a valid identifier

Tags: java, bash, macos, apache-spark

I was trying to install Apache Spark in my Mac. After I installed it, I got this error every time I run java.

`` bash: export: `“JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home”': not a valid identifier ``

How I can fix it?

Comment: Don't use non-ASCII quote characters, i.e. don't use `“` and `”`, but only `"`?

Comment: Don't edit source code with a word processor, use a plain text editor. If you're using TextEdit, make sure you turn off smart quote replacement.

Comment: @Barmar  I was trying to install Apache Spark. After I installed it, I got this error every time I run java.

Comment: Spark doesn't use JDK 9, yet, does it?

Answer (score 1):

The line should be:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home
```

with no quotes around it. It seems you misread the installation instructions; the quotes were not intended to be copied literally.

Comment: You may need to open a new Terminal window to reload your `.profile`.

Comment: It's not working do you know to switch back to java 8?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. open `~/.bash_profile` and I found this line:

`“JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.jdk/Contents/Home”` 
and I deleted. After that I wrote this line in the terminal:

`` export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 ``